# Alert Dialog not being shown inside fragment

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have looked at numerous other threads regarding my problem and still can't find the answer. My alert dialog for some reason isn't being shown inside my fragment. Using the same code and modifying slightly, works fine inside an activity. Can anyone spot my mistake?

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_update, null);
builder.setView(view);

builder.create();
TextView txtMessage = view.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
txtMessage.setText("SAVING");

final Dialog popupDialog = builder.show();
popupDialog.setCancelable(false);
popupDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Comment: At what operation you're trying to show it

Comment: When saving a large amount of data to the database, I'm trying to show the popup.

Comment: See DialogFragment

Comment: Layout inflater should be
`LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null, false);`

Comment: @jmckie I have used your exact your code snippet and it's working in my project so explain me exact problem

Comment: @AshishKakadiya I call the method when saving some data to the database, the popup doesn't show and obviously I want to dismiss when the save has completed.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflator();
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_update, null);

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: That's what the builder.show does as I need to specify a custom layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_update, null);
TextView txtMessage = view.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
txtMessage.setText("SAVING");

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
.setView(view)
.setCancelable(false)
.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_update, null);
            final Dialog popupDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setView(view)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .create();
            TextView txtMessage = view.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
            txtMessage.setText("SAVING");
            popupDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by using an Async task

```
class SaveTrainingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Boolean, Boolean> {
        Dialog popupDialog;

        public SaveTrainingTask() {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_update, null);
            TextView txtMessage = view.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
            txtMessage.setText("SAVING TRAINING");
            builder.setView(view);

            builder.create();

            popupDialog = builder.show();
            popupDialog.setCancelable(false);
            popupDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        }

        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... urls) {
            saveInspection();
            return true;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            popupDialog.dismiss();

            if (result) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Successfully saved training.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SelectEquipmentActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                getActivity().finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error saving training.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```